# ¿Cómo mostrar resultado de consulta SQL en un solo campo en ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, sqlfiddle

Se tiene la siguiente tabla llamada `P_FAMILIA`:

```
|ID |    NAME    | SOLDADOS   |
|---|------------|------------|
| 1 | Stark      |  30000     |
| 2 | Targaryen  |            |
| 3 | Lannister  |  15000     |
| 4 | Greyjoy    |            |
```

Al realizar la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT F.NAME 
FROM P_FAMILIA F
```

Obtengo

```
|    NAME    |
|------------|
| Stark      |
| Targaryen  |
| Lannister  |
| Greyjoy    |
```

Deseo mostrar el resultado de la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
|            NAME                 |
|---------------------------------|
|Stark,Targaryen,Lannister,Greyjoy|
```

**Actualización**

Intente subir el esquema a [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com) pero la aplicación presenta problemas cuando se elige el motor "`Oracle 11g R2`"

Esquema:

```
-- Crear tabla
CREATE TABLE P_FAMILIA
(
ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
SOLDADOS FLOAT(126)
);

-- Llave primaria
ALTER TABLE P_FAMILIA
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

    -- Insert Statements
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME, SOLDADOS)
 Values
   (1, 'Stark', 30000);
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME)
 Values
   (2, 'Targaryen');
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME, SOLDADOS)
 Values
   (3, 'Lannister', 15000);
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME)
 Values
   (4, 'Greyjoy');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: no utilizo oracle, Pero utilizo postgresql con lenguaje Pl-sql y al crear una función que en este caso seria Create or replace function myfunc() RETURNS TABLE(id numeric,name text,soldados numeric) AS $BODY$  BEGIN   RETURN query SELECT *
FROM P_FAMILIA F; END;  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE     y al ejecutarlo lo hago como select myfunc (que no es lo mismo que select *from myfunc) y me trae los datos como vos necesitas.

Comment: Gracias @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo voy a intentarlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entiendo que por el ejemplo que has dado que lo que buscas es esto:

```
select listagg(A.NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.ID) as NAME from P_FAMILIA A;
```

De no ser así, te pido que describas en detalle en que no se parece a lo que pides.

Por cierto, [LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/) de Oracle si funciona, por si quieres hacer pruebas y compartir.

Comment: Si señor, ese era el resultado que esperaba. no conocia el LiveSQL de Oracle, bastante útil gracias por compartir. este sería el esquema y la consulta: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_DVDUPIR1ZUXI2GNJIP0L7T9HL.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(NAME) AS NAMECONCATS FROM P_FAMILIA GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: Gracias Hector pero me muestra el resultado de la misma forma...

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para poder hacer concatenar los valores de las filas

**Podrías usar una función para que te devuelva los datos agrupados o un bloque anonimo:**

```
<br/>
set serveroutput on
<br/>
declare
<br/>
cursor c_name is select name from P_FAMILIA;
<br/>
name_2 varchar2(50);
<br/>
begin
<br/>
  name_2:='';
<br/>
  for x in c_name loop
<br/>
    if c_name%rowcount = 1 then
<br/>
     name_2:=name_2||' '||x.name;
<br/>
    else
<br/>
      name_2:=name_2||', '||x.name;
<br/>
    end if;
<br/>
  end loop;
<br/>
  dbms_output.put_line(name_2);  
<br/>
end;
<br/>
/
<br/>
<br/>
```

**O puedes usar las funciones analíticas "LEAD" o "LAG"**

```
select * from (
<br/>select name||' ,'||
<br/>**lag**(name,1) over (order by name)||' ,'||
<br/>**lag**(name,2) over (order by name) ||' ,'||
<br/>**lag**(name,3) over (order by name)
<br/>NAME_2  from P_FAMILIA
<br/>order by NAME_2 desc ) 
<br/>where rownum=1;

select * from (
<br/>select name||' ,'||
<br/>**lead**(name,1) over (order by name)||' ,'||
<br/>**lead**(name,2) over (order by name) ||' ,'||
<br/>**lead**(name,3) over (order by name)
<br/>NAME_2 from P_FAMILIA
<br/>order by NAME_2)
<br/>where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto debe de funcionar (consulta de ejemplo):

```
select stragg(name) from emp;
```

Mostraría:

```
Gonzalo, Juan, José
```

**EDICIÓN**

Puedes probar esto:

```
SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp GROUP BY deptno;
```

Resultado

```
   DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
```

---

```
    10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
    20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
    30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias pero me aparece el siguiente error: ORA-00904: "STRAGG": identificador no válido, tal parece stragg no está disponible para Oracle 11g

Comment: Ya edité, prueba si funciona.

Comment: No da el resultado que estoy buscando ...